# Tracing remote session

Tags: oracle

So, in one of our databases we are seeing a query which is having a lot of wait time.  When we look up the SQL ID and look in the DB, we're not finding that query.  When we look in v$session, we see that the MACHINE is a different physical machine, running other databases.   So, we're guessing that this is possibly being done over a DB link maybe, but we're not finding the SQL code on that server either.

Is there a way for me to see in v$session or v$process any data that would tell me what session on the remote DB is executing this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database link session will show up with `type` = `'USER'` and `program` = `'oracle@....'` All other sessions with a program starting with 'oracle@' should be background processes. You will also see `osuser` = `'oracle'` (if that's what you install your Oracle databases under) and the `machine` will be a server (likely a remote one, but not always) hosting a database.

**The target of a link connection will display a client process/pid that matches the OS pid of the *shadow process* on the source database server.**

So, once you identify the local dblink session, you note its `process` and `machine` fields. If there is only one database on that host (`machine`), it would have to be that one; you can log into it. If there are multiple databases on that host, you can use `ps` locally on that host to find what instance the pid identified by `process` above is attached to:

```
> ps -fp 96505

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
oracle   96505     1  0 18:39 ?        00:00:00 oracleSID (LOCAL=NO)
```

Where `SID` is the actual instance name of your database. Log into that database.

Once in the database that is the source of the link, assuming you're logged into the instance *local* to that node (if RAC), look for the process that has that `spid` (note the `s` in `spid`):

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM v$process p,
       v$session s
 WHERE p.spid = 96505 -- from `process` earlier
   AND p.addr = s.paddr
```

This will be your originating session. You can then reference `sql_id` and grab the SQL from `v$sqlarea` and proceed with your investigation.